# What does htmlentities exactly do with string htmlentities in it?

Tags: php

```
var_dump(htmlentities("&lt;space&gt;"));
```

returns `string(21) "&lt;space&gt;",`

21 chars huh ?

Comment: Ah I see now, the & becomes &amp;

Comment: Likely you are viewing it in your browser. If you view the source code, you should see it how it actually is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's whitespace or special formatting.

`"&amp;lt;space&amp;gt;"` = 21 characters.

Answer (score 2):

Actually it returns something else:

```
<? var_dump(htmlentities("&lt;space&gt;")); ?>
string(21) "&amp;lt;space&amp;gt;"
```

What you saw was the **unescaped** version of your escaped string :).

Answer (score 0):

Because it converted the ampersand to its HTML entity.

```
& => &amp;
```

So, you really ended up with the string:

```
&amp;lt;space&amp;gt;
```

Which is 21 characters.

You can view the source on your browser to see the exact string above. If you don't view the source, the browser converts `&amp;` back to `&`, which is why you only see `&lt;space&gt;`.